# Error correction about modality

Tags: grammar, modality

Error correction: They say it **(1)can** **(2)be going to rain** so you **(3)should** take an umbrella or you **(4)might** get wet.

In this sentence, choose a phrase (1,2,3,4) and change it so that the new sentence is the most correct.

My teacher told me the most correct answer is "They say it **could** (remove "can") be going to rain so you should take an umbrella or you might get wet." He said I can't write "They say it can **rain** (remove "be going to rain") so you should take an umbrella or you might get wet." because it would conflict with the context (something about possibility and probability). He didn't explain more and told me to review past lessons.  I don't have any clue about this. Can someone explain this to me, please?

Comment: I don't understand anything from your question. If your answer is related to 1 and 2, why do you have numbers 3 and 4, then? Also can't isn't given as an option in your sentence. The weather forecast says it's going to rain. So, you should take an umbrella with you, or you might get wet. This is correct. This is also correct: They say it can rain, so you should take an umbrella, or you might get wet.

Comment: @AliE Thank you for voicing for concerns, error correction means choosing a part of question (A, B, C, D) that you think is incorrect and fix it. The "fix" means rewrite the sentence in the most correct way, if it's not possible to be absolutely correct. I thought this type of question is common for second language learner so I didn't provide more context, sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry, this is not a common type of question for me. I will write my answer as an "answer", then.

Comment: If you are asked to change one of the four numbered phrases, I would change (1) to **could**. Your teacher's suggestion of **might** is OK, but that word already occurs in the sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting Actually he listed some modal verbs can be used, I just happen to write the least appropriate here. Thanks.

Comment: It would be easier to understand (for people not familiar with this kind of exercise) if you wrote the full sentences. I guess you answered "They say it can rain so you should take an umbrella or you might get wet." (But that only makes sense if other people might assume it can't ever rain.)

Comment: @StuartF, sorry I can't quite understand your comment. Do you mean after somebody assume it can't ever rain, the sentence is a follow-up to the former sentence to affirm the speaker's belief that it can rain?

Comment: "They say it can rain (from "be going to rain")"=no. They say it can rain at this time of year in India. But it does not come "from" be going to rain.

Comment: @Lambie Thank you, I think you are getting something wrong here. My answer is not shortening "be going to rain" but removing "be going to rain" and replace it with "rain".

Answer (score 0):

I rephrase the question:

> They say it (1) *can* rain ...

or

> They say it (2) *BE going to* rain ...

[be going to](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/be-going-to) is defined in Collins Dictionary:

> PHRASE A2
> If you say that something *is going to* happen, you mean that it will happen in the future, *usually quite soon* [emphasis added].

[can](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can) is defined in M+W:

> can 1 of 5 verb (1) auxiliary verb 1c
> — > used to indicate possibility

> Do you think he can still be alive?

> Those things can happen

The immediacy is not in *can* as opposed to *be going to*, and hence the latter should be used.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'd like the explain more that this type of question, error correction, means choosing a part of question (A, B, C, D) that you think is incorrect and fix it. The "fix" means rewrite the sentence in the most correct way, if it's not possible to be absolutely correct. I thought this question is common for non-native english learner so I didn't provide enough clarity, apologise for that. So in this case, the correct answer is A, can->might. But I wonder why B, (be going to rain)->rain is not correct. I hope you have a clearer idea now.

Comment: You were asking which is to be used: (1) *can* or (2) *be going to*.  The answer is (2) as I've explained.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply, I have seen your insightful reply and I wholeheartedly appreciate that you provided sources and neatly organise your answer. I know it might sound chessy and sarcastic from the first glance but from the bottom of my heart, I'm grateful to have someone as knowledgeable and conscientious as you to stumble upon my post. However I can't help but wonder you might have misunderstood something. You seems to  slightly misread the question, it's about correcting an error than choosing a phrase in the given sentence.

Comment: I'll be eternally thankful if you can provide a more accurate answers with that in mind. You are the only expert I have ever found to ask about this topic.

Comment: This answer misunderstands the question, and in addition is not good information even aside from that. "They say it be going to rain" is not idiomatic in standard English (though it's acceptable in some dialects), and should not be used by language learners unless they are specifically learning a dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Your sentence doesn't work because it is talking about whether it is possible for rain to fall, rather than talking about the probability of rain falling. "Can" and "can't" are a binary; either something is able to happen or it is not. The thing is possible, or it is impossible.

The statement "It can rain" means "Rain is able to fall." This is true whether the chance of rain is 0.0000001% or 100%.

> They say it can rain so you should take an umbrella or you might get wet.

This sentence means, "They say that rain is able to fall, so you should take an umbrella or you might get wet." This is an odd thing to say because on Earth rain is always able to fall, so, if you followed the advice, you would always have to carry an umbrella.

You might expect to hear the phrase "It can rain here" in a place where it is surprising that rain is possible. For example, you might say, "I'm on Mars, and it can rain here!" to express your surprise that it is possible for rain to fall on Mars. Similarly, "It can rain in this building" would be a useful statement to make because you wouldn't expect rain to be able to fall inside a building.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I was worried that no one will come across my question at this point. However, I think you could have limited your view to the dynamic function of the word "can". Here, the epistemic function of this modal verb might be used to indicate probability of rain. I may have misunderstood the second function so could you correct me, if you please?

Comment: Speaking epistemically with "possible" is actually more accurate in this case, but I was avoiding it because you seem to have a confused understanding of that word. "Can" here is epistemic, but expresses the binary between possible and impossible, where possible encompasses everything from a 100% certainty to a .000001% chance.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and dedication. I think I have misunderstood something so I'll try to explain what I learnt from my teacher. The dynamic function of a modal word is to describe the ability/volition of a subject. "Can" has the highest degree of modality among common modal verbs in this function, therefore it express the possibility (a constigency that may happen regardless of probability). The characters limit doesn't allow me to write any longer so I'll make another comment.

Comment: It is because it is "regardless of probability" that "can" is incorrect here. Let us take a day where chance of rain = 100%. "It can rain today" is true. Now let us take a day where chance of rain = 0.000001%. "It can rain today" is true. Because of this, it is not useful for this situation.

Comment: Continue from where I left off. But modal verb also has epistemic function, which implies someone's logical deduction/observation of an event. Here, "can" has lower degree of modality than "would" but higher than "may". For example, this studies shows new medications can cure cancer. So the sentence in question can talk about a possibility of raining (which can be inferred to be fairly high). That's the basic pattern that modal verbs tend to follow. However, I don't fully understand the nuances and intricacies of English language so I believe my understanding could be wrong or incomplete.

Comment: "Can" merely describes the ability for something to happen. So "I can go to the store" is less forceful than "I will go to the store" or even "I might go to the store". It is true in any situation where the event is not impossible, and merely shows ability. "It can rain" = "Rain is possible". "I can go to the store" = "It is possible for me to go to the store." You absolutely cannot infer a high probability of it happening from that, or even any probability other than 0.

Comment: Thank you for being conscientious and patient to my imbecile answers. My teacher told me that if a modal verb has the most basic function (dynamic), then it should have epistemic function. He even started with the word "can" as an example so I don't think it should be an exception. But he remarked that there's still so much to learn about modality so I will keep an open mind. I'm all ears if there's a source written about this. One more thing, the reference my teacher mainly use is Oxford guide to English grammar. I'll review your source about modal verb to see where I'm wrong.

Comment: Oh by the way, I saw you used the word "binary". I can't find it anywhere so can you explain more about that, I want to learn about new concepts. Thank you for your invaluable commitment to helping me.

Comment: Binary means "one or the other". Yes or no. Can or can't. Possible or impossible. True or false. Something can't be both at once. As for modal verbs, they are not a spectrum of probability. They each have their own meanings you must learn.

Comment: Another thing you may be hung up on is that "can" can't be used to express certainty, only its negative "can not" or "can't" can express certainty. So "I can't be sick" means I'm certain that I'm not sick, but "I can be sick" doesn't mean that I'm certain that I am sick. "I can be sick" can only mean "I am able to be sick".

Comment: Thank you, I will ask my teacher because he directly said "can" can describe probability in appropriate context. But if possible, I'd like to see your sources about modality and perhaps topology of modality.

Comment: I'm not aware of any context where "can" is able to independently express probability. Merriam-Webster lists a possible edge case with "can hardly" (https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/can), but that's extremely unusual and I'm not certain that it actually does express probability rather than some aspect of certainty. "Can" expresses possibility.